# GTM Variable: Execute regex on click element to retrieve parent class name

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I would like to extract the class name of a parent element via a Google Tag Manager variable. Tag and trigger work without any problems. Unfortunately, the regex always returns undefined.

When a link is clicked, a part of the class name of a parent container has to be extracted.

```
foo tag-container--bar baz
=> bar
```

**Expected result:**

```
{ 
  link_url: "https://www.example.tld/#a",
  container_name: "bar", // {{Regex Variable}}
}
```

**Result received:**

```
{ 
  link_url: "https://www.example.tld/#a",
  container_name: undefined,
}
```

**Example markup:**

```
<div class="foo tag-container--bar baz">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#a">Link A</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#a">Link B</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Regex variable:**

```
Type: Regex table 
Variable: Click Element 
Pattern: (.*?)(tag-container--)([\S]+)
Output: $3
```

**API response:**

```
dataLayer.push({ 
event: "gtm.linkClick", 
gtm.element: "https://www.example.tld/: html > body > .foo.tag-container--bar.baz > .card > a", 
… 
})
```

Could it have something to do with the fact that the click element is an object and not a string?